# Problem Manipulating Raspberry Pi with Perl

Tags: perl, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying with the perl code below to detect moisture on a Raspberry Pi moisture sensor and take action (send an email) if moisture is detected. The code does appear to succeed in getting an accurate reading from the sensor, however it crashes my program with error:

```
cleaned up, exiting...

original error: Can't locate object method "tid" via package "threads" at /usr/share/perl/5.28/XSLoader.pm line 111.
```

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use RPi::DHT11;
use RPi::WiringPi;
use RPi::Const qw(:all);

my $pi = RPi::WiringPi->new;
my $pin = $pi->pin(21);
my $state = $pin->read;
$pi->cleanup;

if ($state == 0) {

    print "The sensor detected moisture.\n";
    # send an email
    my ($msg, $user, $pass) = build_message();

eval {

    print "Executing in eval.\n";

    my ($reply) = $msg->send('smtp','mail.rushlogistics.com',
                 AuthUser=>$user, AuthPass=>$pass);

    print "Reply was: " . $reply . "\n"; # only prints here if there was no problems

    };


} else {

    print "The sensor is dry.\n";


    }
```

Sending a message earlier in the code before checking the sensor works fine. Commenting out the my ($reply) = $msg->send line also works fine. I get no errors (of course no message is sent either.)

If I add `use threads;` I get thr following errors:

```
The sensor detected moisture.
Executing in eval.
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>> MIME::Lite::SMTP
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>   Net::SMTP(3.11)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>     Net::Cmd(3.11)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>       Exporter(5.73)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket::IP(0.39)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>       IO::Socket(1.39)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>         IO::Handle(1.39)
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)<<< 220 mail42c28.carrierzone.com ESMTP Bigfoot 1.0; Fri, 15 May 2020 21:37:11 +0000
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)<<< 250-mail42c28.carrierzone.com Hello 63-151-32-226.dia.static.qwest.net [63.151.32.226], pleased to meet you
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)<<< 250-8BITMIME
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)<<< 250-SIZE 52428800
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)<<< 250-DSN
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)<<< 250-AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)<<< 250-STARTTLS
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)<<< 250-DELIVERBY
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x24b01f8)<<< 250 HELP

cleaned up, exiting...

original error: SMTP auth() command failed: Invalid argument
mail42c28.carrierzone.com Hello 63-151-32-226.dia.static.qwest.net [63.151.32.226], pleased to meet you
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
8BITMIME
SIZE 52428800
DSN
AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5
STARTTLS
DELIVERBY
HELP
```

Comment: How did you install/build your `perl` binary? Does it support threads?

Comment: Did this to set up my local lib:curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus local::lib --local-lib=~/perl5

echo 'eval $(perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5/ -Mlocal::lib)' >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: Can you check if your `perl` supports threads: `perl -MConfig -E'say ($Config{useithreads}?"ok":"not ok")'` If the output is "not ok" then it does not support threads

Comment: I got 'ok' back when I ran your command. So it looks like it does.

Comment: Ok, good. Where does the output `cleaned up, exiting...` come from ?

Comment: I do not know exactly but I believe that it comes from RPi::WiringPi as it seems that it interrupts the program while MIME::Lite is trying to send the email. Oops, wait. Now I am not sure. Doing some checking. will report back.

Comment: I have not used a Raspberry PI, so I cannot test the modules in your program. It would be helpful if you could determine which line in the script produces the error message. Try add `print` statements after each line for example to determine the place where the error occurs

Comment: Working on tracking down where the error is coming from.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, It's from a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler setup by RPi::WiringPi

Comment: Does adding `use threads;` help?

Comment: Sending a message earlier in the code before checking the sensor works fine. Commenting out the my ($reply) = $msg->send line I get no errors (of course no message is sent either.) If I add use threads; I get:  cleaned up, exiting... original error: Can't locate Authen/SASL/XS.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Authen::SASL::XS module). If I try to install it via: cpanm Authen::SASL::XS I get: ! Configure failed for Authen-SASL-XS-1.00. Can't link/include C library 'sasl.h', 'sasl', aborting.
-> N/A

Comment: Clarify the question by editing the question instead of putting these details in comments.

Comment: Will do Brian. Hope you are well. -Old acquaintance from the Chicago PM days circa 1997.

Comment: `Can't link/include C library 'sasl.h'` Try to install the header files for SASL. If you are using Ubuntu you can try `sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev`

Comment: Installing libsasl2-dev allowed me to get Authen::SASL::XS installed. But when I add 'use threads' it causes Mime::Lite to crash while sending the email with the errors in edited version of the question above.

Comment: *"SMTP auth() command failed: Invalid argument"* : From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite) it seems like you can pass `Debug => 1` to the `send()` method. Maybe you can get some more debugging information like that?

Comment: Yes it did give more info. Edited above.

Comment: Very mysterious that the RPi::Wiring part of the script causes Mime::Lite to fail in authentication.

Comment: RPi::WiringPi does not cause Mime::Lite to not work. Before you initiate anything mail related, you've already destroyed the Pi object entirely. The software definitely does hijack signal handlers, as it has to do hardware cleanup to ensure a consistent state at shutdown. It also doesn't require threads, unless you use interrupts, which you're not. All of that is in the documentation.

Comment: Also, why are you loading the DHT11 class? That's a hygrometer. Are you actually using a DHT11 sensor? Your code is completely wrong for that, or for reading any moisture sensor. `$pin->read` checks the HIGH/LOW status of a digital pin. There are no analog inputs on a Pi without additional hardware. You need to specify what you're trying to do.

Comment: @stevieb Thank you for the reply. What I am trying to do is the same as here: https://www.instructables.com/id/Soil-Moisture-Sensor-Raspberry-Pi/ trying to get the moisture sensor to detect moisture (but with perl instead of python). Additionally, I am try to have my perl script send me an email with results --something I have done with MIME::Lite on several other projects.